# Node Express Busboy Files and Fields Upload

Tags: node.js, file-upload, multipartform-data, express-4, busboy

When using Busboy with express to handle image uploads, I can get the fields and files of a multipart/form-data post like so:

```
var busboy = require('connect-busboy');
app.use(busboy());
app.post('/something', function(req,res) {
    req.pipe(req.busboy);
    req.busboy.on('field', function(fieldname, val) {
         // do stuff here with fields... 
    }
    req.busboy.on('file', function (fieldname, file, filename) {
        // do stuff here with the file
    }
});
```

What I'm wondering is, say there's an instance where I want to know what the fields are before I go about handling the file. It appears in my experimentation that the fields are gotten first every time. Does anyone know if this is guaranteed to always be the case?

Comment: were you able to solve this? I am in a similar situation.

Comment: I do think I had a solution, but it was long ago and I abandoned the project. However if memory serves, what I did in my particular case (I think) was I used "req.busboy.on('finish', function() {.." The 'finish' doesn't fire until everything is done, so in my file and field handlers all I did was store the values and then once the 'finish' function fired is when I did stuff with them.